# Autoplay HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to set an HTML5 video element on iOS Safari to autoplay on page load.

I know that a video can only be triggered from a user event. Here's my scenario.

I have a list of videos on `/videos.html` for example. That list of videos has a play button that takes the user to `/videos/my-video.html`

I don't want to the user to have to click 'play' again while on this URL. In my mind, they've already triggered the user event from the previous page.

Do I have any options here?

Comment: Browsers purposefully prevent this behavior.

Comment: You shouldn't do this

Comment: I understand why browsers do it but in this case, the user has submitted an event to play the video, just from another page

Comment: the condition is reset every page load, so the fix is simple: don't leave the page to play the video, use a modal or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use "autoplay" attribute to play video on page load. Add this attribute dynamically to HTML video element on the click event of play button in /videos.html. You can also use "muted" attribute to play video on mute by default.

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```